# Add a delay between ajax get requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a script that makes an ajax GET request once the user gets near the bottom of the page.

```
$(function(){ 
   window.addEventListener('scroll', fetchImages);
   window.addEventListener('scroll', fetchNotifications);
});

function fetchImages() {

    var imagePage = $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page');

    if(imagePage !== null) {

        var last = $('.endless-pagination').data('last-item');

        var within = $('.endless-pagination').data('within');

        var orderBy = $('.endless-pagination').data('order-by');

        clearTimeout( $.data( this, "scrollCheckImages" ) );

        $.data( this, "scrollCheckImages", setTimeout(function() {

            var scroll_position_for_images_load = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() + 900;

            if(scroll_position_for_images_load >= $(document).height()) {
                $(".dual-ring-container").show();
                $.ajax({
                    url: imagePage,
                    method: 'get',
                    cache: false,
                })
                .done(function( data ) {
                    if (last != null) {
                        $(".dual-ring-container").hide();
                        var newPageUrl =  data.next_page + "&within=" + within + "&orderBy=" + orderBy + "&last=" + last;
                        $('.endless-pagination').append(data.images);
                        $('.endless-pagination').data('next-page', newPageUrl);
                        setResizeVariables();
                        updateReadMore();
                        initMentions();
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 350))
    }
}
```

However, there's a bit of a problem. This get request is essentially being spammed since the function is being triggered by a "scroll" event listener.

[image: console]

How could I make it so that this request can only be called once every few seconds or so?

Comment: What you want to do is essentially debounce the scroll event. https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable that keeps track of the last time the main body of the function was run, and return early if it was run less than a few seconds ago:

```
let lastCall = 0;
function fetchImages() {
  const now = Date.now();
  if (now - lastCall < 3000) return;
  lastCall = now;
  // ...
```

Note that you can use a similar strategy to reduce unnecessary indentation hell. Rather than

```
  if (imagePage !== null) {
    // big block of code
  }
} // end of fetchImages
```

you can use

```
if (imagePage === null) return;
```

which will have the exact same effect, but will make your code a bit more readable.